# Issue with Dagger: cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger

I do have a method annotated w/ `@Provides`, but somehow it's still failing building with this error:

```
Router1Component.java:13: error: com.nice.AbcServiceClient cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Here's my module:

```
@Module
public final class Router1Module {

    @Provides
    public AbcServiceClient provideServiceClient() {
        return new ClientBuilder();
    }
}
```

Here's my interface:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {Router1Module.class})
public interface Router1Component {
    @LambdaHandler
    Router1Lambda buildRouter1Lambda();
}
```

Here's my class:

```
public class Router1Lambda {

    private AbcServiceClient serviceClient;

    @Inject
    public Router1Lambda(
            final AbcServiceClient serviceClient
    ) {
        this.serviceClient = serviceClient;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't add superfluous tags: you're asking a question about Dagger, there was absolutely no reason to also include Spring and Guice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a mix of imports.

I imported `@Provides` from GoogleGuice instead of Dagger, that's why Dagger keeps complaining this error...